# Is there a significance of the novel left behind "Here Comes a Candle"?

Tags: analysis, the-sandman

In *The Sandman* S01E11 second part, after Calliope got free there was "Here Comes a Candle" left behind. It's the same novel Erasmus Fry wanted to be reprinted. Is there any significance of this specific novel or its title to the episode?

Comment: I'd wondered that too - but it's a fairly clichéd book title to use for a horror/mystery writer. The title itself comes from the nursery rhyme, [Oranges & Lemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oranges_and_Lemons) "…here comes a candle to light you to bed, and here comes a chopper to chop off your head"

Comment: @Tetsujin Also referenced in [the boys S03E07](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt14246406/) episode title

Answer (score 9):

As [explained by executive producer **Allan Heinberg**](https://www.netflix.com/tudum/articles/the-sandman-episode-calliope-ending-explained):

> When Nora goes to free Calliope, all she finds in the room is a copy of *Here Comes a Candle*, the novel Erasmus desperately sought to get back into print. What do you think the symbolism is behind that?
>
> That scene comes from the comic book. I think at that moment, **the muse is gone and the product of her time there is what’s left behind in the world.**
>
> I think readers and viewers can interpret it in a number of different ways: This creature was held prisoner for decades upon decades only for this — this thing that isn’t in print or that people aren’t even reading. Or it can also be taken as a sign that literature lives on and hopefully sends a message to future generations about the dangers of sacrificing others for one’s own advantage.

Answer (score 8):

*Here Comes a Candle* was the novel that Fry had written on his own, before capturing Calliope.  He had no ideas for a follow-up and seemed destined to be a one-hit wonder.

To me, it seemed that Fry's tremendous success with the work of his captured Muse did not actually bring him happiness.  Yes, the world believed he was a successful writer, but he knew that only that first book was his creation, and it only existed in used book stores and old collections.  He felt like a fraud and wanted the validation that could be had of someone desiring to reprint his masterpiece.

Comment: "Here Comes a Candle was the novel that Fry had written on his own" - did it explicitly say that? I also got that impression, from the way Fry said "I was particularly proud of that one", but I don't remember anything that stated it clearly